# How to create alias for python package (specifically KERAS)

Tags: python, ubuntu, keras

Is there some kind of workaround to create alias for python package..

What I want to do is to create an alias such that

```
from keras import LSTM
```

and the following code are same.

```
from albatross import LSTM
```

NOTE: I tried installing Keras from the github repo by modifying the name of the package in setup.py, but it is of no use.

Is there any way to do this in python (3) ?

EDIT: 
I'm not interested in the following way, as I don't want keras to be specified anywhere in the program code

```
import keras as albatross
```

Comment: import keras as albatross

Comment: I want to create a system wide alias... possibly without the use of this type of alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a UNIX system, then a link will do what you want.
Suppose you want to import the `keras` module, but with the name `albatross`.
You can first find where the `keras` module is installed, by importing it and looking at its `file` attribute:

```
$ python
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> keras.__file__
'/home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py'
```

Now, you can create a symbolic link to the `keras/` directory, right next to it:

```
$ cd /home/<username>/.local/lib/python3.5site-packages
$ ln -s keras albatross
```

You'll find yourself with a link named `albatross`, pointing to the `keras` directory.
Now, importing `albatross` will work, system-wide, and will effectively import `keras`:

```
$ python
>>> import albatross
Using TensorFlow backend.
```